# Finding the minimum number of moves to achieve equal array elements

Tags: c#, array

Long story short, the other day I discovered the site **LeetCode** and started solving some of its problems until I stumbled onto [this one](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-moves-to-equal-array-elements/).

I'll paste the description here:

> Given a non-empty integer array of size n, find the minimum number of
>   moves required to make all array elements equal, where a move is
>   incrementing n - 1 elements by 1.
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> [1,2,3]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> 3
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> Only three moves are needed (remember each move increments two
>   elements): [1,2,3]  =>  [2,3,3]  =>  [3,4,3]  =>  [4,4,4]

The problem is, the solution I am trying to submit always exceeds the allowed processing time limit and I feel like I've reached a dead end. Can anyone suggest a way to improve my code?

```
 static void Main()
    {
        int res = MinMoves(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
    }
    public static int MinMoves(int[] nums)
    {
        if (nums.Length < 2)
            return 0;

        int moves = 0;
        int diff = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int maxIX = 0;
        do
        {
            min = nums.Min();
            max = nums.Max();
            maxIX = Array.IndexOf(nums, max);
            diff = Math.Abs(max - min);
            moves += diff;
            for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
                if (i != maxIX)
                    nums[i] += diff;

        } while (min != max);

        return moves;
    }
```

Comment: What is the processing time limit?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, the site performs several checks, not just the one I posted, with much larger arrays. The time limit seems to be 1-2 seconds at most. I feel like the only way to achieve this is without iterating through the array more than once, but I can't come up with a way.

Comment: The problem is the same as "... where a move is *decrementing* a *single* element by one".  Do you see why?  Is it easier to see the answer when you re-cast the problem in this way?

Comment: To me it looks like incrementing n-1 element equals decrementing 1 element. That is [1,2,3] => [2,3,3] is equivalent to [1,2,3] => [2,3,2], and the whole sequence then looks like this: [1,2,3] => [1,2,2] => [1,2,1] => [1,1,1]

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: I think you meant to say "incrementing n-1 elements equals decrementing one element" -- but yes, we are having the same thought at the same time here. :)

Comment: @EricLippert although, it's much easier to hit an execution time limit if you are operating on more elements. I'd probably code the move as a decrement, but provided a class property to transform the array in the "end form" as if elements were being incremented. Then I only need to call this property once at the end of the challenge, so I have both speed and the desired result.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: There is no need to implement the actual moves at all. The problem is to calculate *how many* moves must be done, not *what the sequence of moves is*. You can simply read the number of moves required off of the array values directly.

Comment: @EricLippert, indeed! I stand corrected. In this case, I'll upvote your answer ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem can be re-formulated into a much easier-to-conceptualize form.

Instead of

> Given a non-empty integer array of size n, find the minimum number of moves required to make all array elements equal, where a move is incrementing n - 1 elements by 1.

say instead

> where a move is decrementing a single element by 1

Do you see why these are the same?  Suppose we start with `1, 2, 3`.  Adding `1, 1, 0` produces `2, 3, 3`.  Adding `0, 0, -1` produces `1, 2, 2`, which is *effectively* the same thing. However many moves it takes to make `2, 3, 3` all equal is surely the same number of moves as it takes to make `1, 2, 2`, all equal, or `0, 1, 1`, or `1000, 1001, 1001`, or whatever. Where you start is irrelevant.

Once you know that the problem is actually "how many single decrements does it take to get all the elements equal?" the answer is easily seen. There is never any point in decrementing the smallest element, and every element will have to eventually equal the smallest element. Therefore the answer is: it's the sum of the differences of every element from the minimal element.

That's a trivial program in C#:

```
var min = nums.Min();
return nums.Select(x => x - min).Sum();
```

Or alternatively, in a single line:

```
return nums.Sum() - nums.Length * nums.Min();
```

(Though as noted in the comments, this second version can overflow. Consider doing all the math in longs or BigIntegers if you're worried about overflow cases.)

Comment: Always thought you should be a teacher, between the MSDN articles, blog and answers across the StackExchange, I think you'd be very good at it.  You always have a way of getting readers to come to the solution on their own, instead of just spelling it out at the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff: Thanks, I appreciate the kind words.

Comment: Very nice. Does this solution/technique have a generic name?

Comment: @Gerard: I'm not aware of a name for this specific solution. The general technique of writing methods that read like `items.Select(...).Where(...).Unique().Sum()` -- that is, where operations in a workflow are easily-understood English words and each element in the workflow reads clearly left-to-right is called "fluent programming". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface

Comment: I eventually got to this point but it took me ages and I was getting increasingly frustrated with the "easy" label on leetcode. One thing to note is that leetcode use test cases like `new[] {1, 1, int.MaxValue }` which would cause an overflow in the one liner. Also second @MichaelMcGriff's comment :)

Comment: Excellent, you just blew my mind with how simple it was

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, identify hidden loops, such as `Min`, `Max` and `IndexOf`, and merge those together - as per Paparazzi's answer. There's no need to count to `n` 3 times in a row.

The question asks you to find the number of moves, not to actually execute the number of moves. You've already optimized this by working with `diff` rather than adding just `1` each time. However, this is an optimization for the best-case scenario (e.g., when diff > 1), the worst case performance remains `n^2` with respect to the length of `nums`.

Further optimization could be achieved by removing the lowest duplicated numbers - though this once again is a best-case optimization. (e.g., when your input has few unique numbers).

Finally, rethink the whole thing. Below is what I came up with. It's based on permutations and triangular numbers. I had drafted a proof of sorts, but my lunch break was too short to finish it. Initial unit tests show the output to be identical to your implementation, but requiring just `O(n log(n))` time complexity.

```
public static int GerardMinMoves(int[] nums) {

    // Sort in place. Assumed O(n log(n)) complexity
    Array.Sort(nums);

    int moves = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < nums.Length; ++i) 
    {
        // Difference beween current and previous.
        int delta = (nums[i] - nums[i - 1]);

        // Add current delta to previous deltas
        sum += delta;

        // Triangular number, accumulate.
        moves += sum;
    }

    return moves;
}
```

Comment: Output shows 2, which seems correct. Here is the fiddle for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/g60t3LL0/ (see browser developer console for output)

Comment: This solution appears to be correct and is accepted by leetcode. Would be interested in seeing the proof ;)

Comment: Couldn't you just skip sum and do lastSum =+ delta.  And I think you need to remover duplicate from input.

Comment: Not sure what you entirely mean, but `lastSum` is cached because I don't want to accumulate the sum of sums (recursively), so to speak. An other answer to this question already made that mistake.

Comment: I like your solution, it's very clean, I focused my code on the part of incrementing all but the maximum value element, I wasn't aware the same output could be achieved by summing the delta between pairs of array's elements

Comment: Not seeing how int sum = (lastSum + delta);  lastSum = sum; is different than lastSum =+ delta;

Comment: I thought you meant something else! I've applied your suggestion to the code and removed one temporarily variable.

Comment: This clearly works, and is it intuitive why it does, but I would like to see a proof that it is the optimal number of moves. I suppose a backward iterative demonstration is possible, but it seems tedious.

Comment: Let's examine your answer a little closer. Let's suppose that we have 4 elements x0, x1, x2, x3, and we number each mutation of variables s and m. We have `s1 = x1 - x0`, `m1 = s1`, which is `x1 - x0`. Then `s2 = x2 - x1 + s1`, which is `x2 - x1 + x1 - x0`, which is `x2 - x0`. Then `m2 = m1 + s1`, which is `x1 - x0 + x2 - x0`. And so on; we see that `m3 = x1 - x0 + x2 - x0 + x3 - x0`.  You are doing an awful lot of adding and subtracting in order to compute `(x1 + x2 + x3) - 3 (x0)`!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `Math.Abs`. You are making 3 passes to get `min`, `max`, and `maxIX` - do it in one pass and stop when `min == max`.

```
min = max = num[0];
maxIX = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < nums.Length; i++)
{
    if(nums[i] > max)
    {
        max = nums[i];
        maxIX = i;
    }
    else if (nums[i] < min)
        min = nums[i];
}
if (min != max)
{
     .... 
}
```

The answer may be calculated without actually processing.

Comment: You can further optimize this by setting `min = max = num[0]` and `maxIX = 0` and then starting the loop with `int i = 1`.

Comment: You missed `else` before the second `if`. Should be: `else if (nums[i] < min)`. It's because both `min` and `max` are initialized with the same value, so both conditions can't be true.

Comment: @Paparazzi, you are absolutely right, I keep using these methods separately out of habit because I find them visually attractive, but doing all three in one go is the right way to go